# How to derive the general expression for eigenvalue for the square of Pauli Lubanski operator?

Tags: quantum-spin, lorentz-symmetry, dirac-equation, poincare-symmetry

After some trials, I managed to get the correct eingenvalue $(\frac{-3}{4}m^2)$ for $W^2$, where $W$ is the Pauli Lubanski pseudo vector.

The expression for each $J^{\mu \nu}$ is a sum of a 4x4 matrix, formed by 2x2 Pauli matrices, related to spin, and an expression like $x_{\mu}\partial_{\nu} - x_{\nu}\partial_
{\mu}$, related to orbital angular momentum. That $J^{\mu \nu}$ comes from requiring that the function is a spinor that solves Dirac equation.

I tried then to use $J^{\mu \nu}$ as a 4x4 matrix formed only by zeros and 1's, that result from infinitesimal rotation and "boosts". No requirements about Dirac equation now.

But instead of getting the general expression for the eigenvalue: $-s(s+1)m^2$, I got $2m^2$. (maybe there is a change of sign somewhere).

Anyway, I think that it corresponds to spin = 1: $(1(1+1))$, and is another particular result. Is it right?

How can I get the general expression $-s(s+1)m^2$? What type of $J$ have to be used?

Comment: Can you get  *all* plain angular momentum eigenvalues j(j+1) in the rest frame? You should be able to see the effects on $Y_l^m$s if you have written down the correct expression.

Comment: In both cases, the particle was not taken in its rest frame. That is: all $P^{\alpha}$ are different from zero.

Comment: OK, work out the action on a spin 2 particle.